# Country-list: Looping through country object to render <options> returns error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object

I am using `countries-list` in my React (TSX) app to get all countries: https://github.com/annexare/Countries

The goal is to have a `<Form>` which has a `<Select>` field that renders the countries as `<options>`.

```
<Form.Control
  as="select"
  name="country"
  value={values.country}
  onChange={handleChange}
>                                          
  {
    Object.entries(countries).forEach(([key, val]) =>
      <option value={val.name} key={key}>
        {val.name}
      </option>
    )
  }
</Form.Control>
```

My problem is that I get the following error and have no idea what the problem is as I am fairly new to TypeScript:

> No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly, BsPrefixProps> & FormControlProps>>): FormControl>', gave the following error. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'. Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ReplaceProps, BsPrefixProps> & FormControlProps>, context?: any): FormControl>', gave the following error. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.

I tried also to give `key` and `val` a type `Country` ([key: Country, val: Country]) but this gives even more errors back.

Comment: could you add the whole including the import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a map method:

```
<Form.Control
  as="select"
  name="country"
  value={values.country}
  onChange={handleChange}
>                                          
  {
    Object.entries(countries).map((key, val) => (
      <option value={val.name} key={key}>
        {val.name}
      </option>
    ))
  }
</Form.Control>
```

Comment: Can you explain me why it only works with `.map()`?

Comment: forEach is a method for iteration, map is a method of transformation. There is no output for forEach.

Comment: Note: `Object.entries` will need a polyfill to work in IE.